# 4 dictionaries give "at face value" a slightly different meaning, what should I do?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, ambiguity, dictionaries

I notice someone had asked [What does "to take someone at face value" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20791/what-does-to-take-someone-at-face-value-mean) before. But my question is a bit different.

1. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-face-value said "If you take something at face value, you accept it and believe it without thinking about it very much, **even though it might be untrue**."
2. https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/take-something-at-face-value said "to accept a situation or accept what someone says, **without thinking there may be a hidden meaning**"
3. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sth-at-face-value said "to accept something as it appears to be **rather than studying it more closely**"
4. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20face%20value said "as true or genuine **without being questioned or doubted**”

I am not a native speaker and normally I just use one dictionary (longman most of time). But I have noticed several times that different dictionaries gives a phase a slightly different meanings, "at face value“ is just one example. When that happens what should I do, how can I know which one is the most relevant?

PS, if this question is off-topic here (I have no idea if it is or not) can anyone kindly let me know where I can ask the question.

---

About the meaning of "face value" I actually first learned from merriam-webster, "as true or genuine without being questioned or doubted". So when I read Bruce Springsteen biography "Born to Run", chapter 62 "My mother stood behind my wildest dreams, accepted me at **face value** for who I truly was", it totally makes sense.

But then I read [these words](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617293709) "Whenever I encounter a math formula in the wild, I take a two-step approach. The first is to translate its methods into an intuitive analogy to the real world. I almost never take a formula at **face value**: I break it into parts, each with a story of its own." The longman and cambridge's explanation seem to make more sense.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of another question. If you have a specific question about a usage of the phrase "at face value", then you can ask that, providing information on that specific case. Does this answer your question? [Why do different dictionaries seem to have different nuances in word definitions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/522219/why-do-different-dictionaries-seem-to-have-different-nuances-in-word-definitions)

Comment: The expression 'take X at face value' _is_ polysemous. (a) if X is a person, it means 'regard X as not putting on a front'. What you see is what you get. (b) if X is a statement on everyday matters, it means 'accept X as being the truth, and without looking for sneakily hidden implications / ulterior motives'.  (c) if X is a statement regarding an aspect of a complex issue, it means accepting it without rigorous proof of truth.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the phrase *face value* for its basic meanings:

[Merriam-Webster *face value*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/face%20value)

1 : the value indicated on the face (as of a postage stamp or a stock certificate)
2 : the apparent value or significance
*if their remarks may be taken at face value*

Any of the definitions cited in your question can be seen as valid in the light of the basic meaning of the phrase. In some cases, a mention of *face value* (meaning *apparent value or significance*) means that the actual value may be different from that.

Comment: Hi I updated the my question about why I was bit confused with the meaning of "face value".

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗  The writer seems to be saying that he studies formulas to understand what they mean.  I have to say that the example about math formulas doesn't seem to me like a very apt use of *at face value*.